# Dropdowns don't work on webOS with PhoneGap?

Tags: html, webos, cordova

I'm trying to use a dropdown in a PhoneGap app I'm writing. It uses a simple `<select>`:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

This works fine on Android and the iPhone (including behaving like a native drop-down would on those systems). However, it doesn't appear to work on webOS (neither the Palm Pre itself nor the emulator).

The `<select>` displays properly on the screen, but when I tap on it, nothing happens--I'm not able to make a selection from the dropdown.

Why might this be?

Comment: I'm having the same trouble in Android.

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523309/select-box-not-displaying-on-android-in-phonegap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did some testing ... looks like its not a PhoneGap limitation, but in fact a webOS limitation -- webOS doesn't support select tags (wtf!). So this is a significant discovery ... I wonder what other tags are unsupported.

So will have to start investigating options for this. A script which replaces  tags with Mojo list selector widgets is a thought ... but there may be some hurdles here.

Stay tuned to the phonegap.com blog roll for updates as we look into this.

Comment: That's odd. Select tags work fine in HTML in the web browser. Thanks for your research! I'll keep my eyes peeled.