# <select> box not displaying on Android in PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have some HTML code in a PhoneGap application that displays a `<select>` box to the user. When I tap on it, the usual Android selection screen doesn't pop up. I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877597/dropdowns-dont-work-on-webos-with-phonegap) with this earlier on webOS (although at that time the drop-downs were working properly).

The `<select>` is inside a `<div>` that gets hidden or shown at certain times during execution:

```
<div id="submit">
  <ul class="rounded">
    <li><select id="item"></select></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem only occurs when the `<div>` has been hidden and then shown again (either directly through CSS or by using jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` methods. If I move the `<select>` box outside of that `<div>`, or if I make the `<div>` always visible, then the drop-down behaves as it should; no problems.

Why is this?

Comment: I've noticed the same problem before; on certain simulators/devices I actually got it working but you *have* to tap the little arrow on the select box, not the text. Pretty lame :/

Comment: I wonder if that has something to do with it. jQTouch displays the select box totally differently (i.e., there is no arrow anymore). Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the problem was actually cased by jQTouch. To fix it, just comment out these 4 lines in jqtouch.css

Under "body"

```
  /*-webkit-perspective: 800;*/
  /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
```

Under "body > * "

```
/*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0) scale(1);*/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10280

Comment: I believe you are right. I am hiding and then showing the select box later. Guess we'll just have to wait for the bug to be fixed. :) Thanks for the research!

Comment: I'm living with this bug every day, and it's really annoying. One wierd workaround for it has been to clone all select lists after they become visible. I don't do anything with the cloned elements, though. The cloning in itself seem to somehow trigger Android to make them work properly. Doesn't seem to work in all cases though.

Another thing that I noticed today was that if your select list is placed exactly above another element, the select list can freeze up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on android application which is built on iScroll+Phonegap.
Do not use iScroll