# input type="text" not working in Android/phonegap/jQTouch

Tags: android, cordova, jqtouch

I've got a jQTouch app on Android using phonegap. It had a dropdown which wasn't working. I've since resolved that issue after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523309/select-box-not-displaying-on-android-in-phonegap).  However, I still can't get my input text to work.  The form element seems as if it is disabled (though it is not grayed out).

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="search">
    <ul class="rounded">
        <li>
            <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" id="searchBox" name="searchBox" placeholder="Type your search term here." />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is likely not enough to go on, but there really isn't much more to it than that. I'm  hoping someone is aware of some obscure bug that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

My impression (from experience) with jQTouch is that, it was developed for iOS Safari; but since Android browsers and iOS Safari are both WebKit-based, a lot of functions work on both. If you truly want this app to be functional on Android, your best bet is probably to switch to [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Take a look at the following two posts:

- [Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android

If you want more access than what a browser provides (e.g. accelerometer), just build a simple native wrapper for each platform.